# Liferay redirect to URL from doView

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I need to redirect (after do something) to an URL from doView().

How is it possible?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

From your tags I'm assuming you're writing a portlet, possibly including an actionhandler. Now as soon as you're coming to the render phase, you intend to redirect to a completely different URL (e.g. to redirect your browser to show something outside of the portal) - correct me if I'm wrong.

With this, HTTP redirect is out of the game if you want this to work reliably. (There has been a [lively debate](https://www.liferay.com/de/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/40409040) on the liferay forums on the reasons)

For this reason javascript is your friend if you intend on the redirect to happen during render phase. However, note that this still might interfere with user expectation: Imagine if two different portlets generate different javascript redirects - which one do you expect to win?

Architecturally it might be cleaner to trigger a redirect during the action phase, but that's not your question

Comment: this is my situation. A bank have to send me a background confirmation with a code, I have to process this data and send a confirmation page like "<html><body>ok</body></html>" I don't know how i can do that